# How can i ensure the rackstore block uses the left aisle, and the rackPick block uses the right aisle in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

[image]

Hi,

I have using a Pallet Rack with two aisles. In the image, the left aisle with blue paths I want to use it for rackStore element. And the right aisle with the conveyor element, I want to use it in the rackPick element.

But once i run the model, the agents also go out of the network(the blue on the left) and go to the right aisle first and then to the palletRack.

How can I ensure, the agents use the left aisle for RackStore purpose only?